# How do i limit the daily requests a user can make to using my google maps api key, using the new google console?

Tags: google, google-maps

Google used to allow you to configure a maximum daily amount of API requests per user (ip address). For example if i were to set the maximum amount of daily requests to 50 and a user would make more than 50 map display requests, then that user would get a downgraded version of google maps on the 51th request. This downgraded version would be darker then the regular one and would be water marked with a repeating word pattern that said *for development purposes only*.

But now that the google developers console has changed i can't find this option anymore. Can i still set a maximum daily amount of requests per user or have they removed this option from the console? If they did then what other options are there from a single user spamming requests using my api key? I don't want one malicious user to be able to inflate my monthly google maps bill like that.

EDIT: The [Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/usage-and-billing) does explain how to limit requests that can be made in one day. But those are the total amount of requests that can be made. I need to limit the total requests that one user is allowed to make in one day.